# Animated GIF won't stop looping Winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have an animated gif in a PictureBox on my form but it is always looping, how can I make it only play once?

When viewing the gif in another program (eg a browser) it only plays once, as it should.  However on my form it loops all the time with only a very short jerky pause between loops of the animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That took me a while... Here I obtain number of frames and animate the gif until the end of frames.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim animatedImage As New Bitmap("a.gif")
    Dim currentlyAnimating As Boolean = False
    Dim framecounter As Integer = 0
    Dim framecount As Integer
    Dim framdim As Imaging.FrameDimension
    Private Sub OnFrameChanged(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        PictureBox1.Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Sub AnimateImage()
        If Not currentlyAnimating Then
            ImageAnimator.Animate(animatedImage, New EventHandler(AddressOf Me.OnFrameChanged))
            currentlyAnimating = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
        If framecounter < framecount Then
            AnimateImage()
            ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames()
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Me.animatedImage, New Point(0, 0))
            framecounter += 1
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        framdim = New Imaging.FrameDimension(animatedImage.FrameDimensionsList(0))
        framecount = animatedImage.GetFrameCount(framdim)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you!  Essentially the same answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can determine how long the cycle is, you can stop the animation by disabling the picturebox after the appropriate amount of time.

EDIT: After reviewing the PictureBox source code, it doesn't look like there is a way to modify this behavior in the PictureBox itself.

However, there does appear to be a viable alternative: the [ImageAnimator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageanimator.animate.aspx) class, which is what the PictureBox uses internally. The MSDN article has a good sample of how to animate one time.

Comment: Tried that but with only 100ms between frames it's hard to make sure it stops at exactly the right one.  One frame off and it looks wrong.

Comment: @Sparrowhawk: Updated the answer to include additional information that I discovered and another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple solution.  I created a timer for the total combined time of one loop of the animated gif.  When the timer stops it changes the image to a still picture in the picture box.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\GIF\AnimatedGif.gif")
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\GIF\StillImage.gif")
    Timer1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```